# How to loop through xml file with google app script

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script

I'm fetching the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <product>
        <id>1</id>
        <value>2253</value>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>2</id>
        <value>118</value>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>3</id>
        <value>111</value>
    </product>
    etc...
```

My script looks like this :

```
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getContentText();
    var data = XmlService.parse(response);
    var product = doc.getRootElement().getChild("product").getValue();
```

I'm able to get product values but only for the first item. So for example when trying this `var product = doc.getRootElement().getChild("product")[i].getValue();` I got an error.

What can I do to loop through this kind of xml structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`.getChildren("product")`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getChildren(String)) instead of `.getChild()`. The latter returns the first element that matches that node name, whereas `.getChildren()` returns the array you're trying to loop through.

```
var products = doc.getRootElement().getChildren("product");
for( var i = 0; i < products.length; i++ ) {
    var product = products[i];
    //enter code here
}
```